# If I have 10 attributes that I want updated if a condition is correct, how do I do that?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say I have a set of attributes on my `Client` model like this:

```
#  firm_size                 :float
#  priority_level            :float
#  inflection_point          :float
#  personal_priority         :float
#  sales_priority            :float
#  sales_team_priority       :float
#  days_since_contact        :float
#  does_client_vote          :float
#  did_client_vote_for_us    :float
#  days_until_next_vote      :float
#  does_client_vote_ii       :float
#  did_client_vote_ii_for_us :float
#  days_until_vote_ii        :float
```

And I need to run a check on each attribute like this:

```
max = Max.find_or_create_by_user_id(:user_id => current_user.id)

if client.firm.size > max.firm_size
    max.firm_size = client.firm.size
end

if client.inflection_point > max.inflection_point
    max.inflection_point = client.inflection_point
end
```

And so on for the rest of the attributes, but this seems quite un-DRY to me.

How do I do this in an elegant way, without having to type out 1 billion `if statements` for all the attributes?

Comment: I assume you mistyped: `client.firm.size` should be `client.firm_size`, right?

Comment: No. `size` is an attribute on the model `firm` and `Client` and `Firm` are related.

Comment: Hmm. well that makes it pretty difficult to write a general solution that works for all attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put all the attributes in an array, you could iterate over it and use some metaprogramming to only have to write the logic once:

```
good_attrs = %w(firm_size priority_level ...)

good_attrs.each do |attr|
  if client.send(attr) > max.send(attr)
    max.send("#{attr}=", client.send(attr)
  end
end
```

Comment: Something similar to this is what I had initially thought about - but having to manually write out all the attributes seems a bit inefficient to me. I prefer the `max.attributes` approach.

Comment: I initially thought about suggesting that approach, but did not for a couple reasons. 1) The attributes hash contains all the columns on your model, including id, created_at, updated_at, etc. I'm guessing you'll still need to explicitly filter these out, which requires manually writing some code. 2) Readability - By manually writing out which columns are getting updated, someone reading your code knows exactly what is happening. If you use implicit approach, then someone would need to check the schema to see what was truly happening.

Comment: That's a good consideration, the readability portion. All of my models are annotated, so I will just add a comment for them to review the model to see the attributes. But the point about exempting `id`, `created_at`, `updated_at` and other fields like that is a very good one. I prefer blacklisting a few attributes (in this case, it is just 3) versus whitelisting the dozen.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend against using a blacklist. If you add a new field to your table in a few months that you hadn't intended to be part of the whitelist, you may run into some strange bugs. Chances are you'll have forgotten about the blacklist and all of the sudden fields in your database will be changing and you won't know why. Unless you plan on adding lots of new fields all the time, then I'd still recommend a whitelist. If you ARE adding lots of new fields, I'd consider a different data model.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this (not sure if I understand your objects correct)

```
[ :firm_size, :priority_level, :inflection_point, ... ].each do |attr|
  if client[attr] > max[attr]
    max[attr] = client[attr]
  end
end
```

almost the same...

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Client.column_names.each do |attr_name|
  if (client_val = client.send(attr_name)) > max.send(attr_name)
    max.write_attribute(attr_name, client_val) 
  end
end
```

I'm assuming here that you want to iterate over *all* attributes of the `Client` model, but from the comment thread above, this appears not to be the case.

Comment: This is interesting. Never knew I could do `column_names`. I prefer the `max.attributes` approach though.

Answer (score 1):

First, I'd make a whitelist method in your `client.rb` model of attributes you want to utilize for this type of comparison.

```
def self.comparable_attrs
  %w(firm_size priority_level inflection_point personal_priority ...)
end
```

Then you can loop through all of your good_attrs using the `send()` method.

```
Client.comparable_attrs.each do |attr|
  if client.send(attr) > max.send(attr)
    max.send("#{attr}=", client.send(attr))
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what `send` does here?

Comment: It a way of making method calls out of strings or symbols. So in this loop the `|attr|` values are all strings. So you can't do `max."firm_size"` This wouldn't work. Instead you can do `max.send("firm_size")` which is identical to `max.firm_size`

Comment: I guess it's debatable, but no I wouldn't consider this `meta programming`. Metaprogramming is writing code that generates other code. This is certainly a higher abstraction level, however.

Comment: For what it's worth, I disagree with @joofsh and would consider any sort of dynamic dispatch to be metaprogramming. If your definition is "code that writes code", then this is absolutely metaprogramming. In the case where "attr" is "firm_size", then `max.send("#{attr}=", client.send(attr)` is "writing" code for `max.firm_size = client.firm_size`.

Comment: That is what I was thinking...thanks for weighing in. I guess @joofsh covered his answer by saying "it's debatable". Turns out he is right ;)

Comment: @joofsh Do you have an elegant solution to handle the attributes here that need to be blacklisted (namely `id`, `created_at` & `updated_at`). I am thinking of just creating a new array and `pop` those elements out of the array, then using the modified array in the each loop. But not sure how elegant that is. Thoughts?

Comment: @Beerlington Valid points. In that case would you consider anytime you use `.send()` to be meta programming? Since `.send()` is essentially creating new code based on a string/sym?

Comment: @marcamillion I agree with Beerlington 's answer from below about using a whitelist over blacklist.  I'd create a new method in the Client controller that would spit out an array of "good attributes" Something like: `def self.good_attrs; %w(firm_size priority_level inflection_point etc...); end` And then in your loop you can call `Client.good_attrs.each do |attr|`  instead.

Comment: @joofsh Yes I'd consider anything using send() to be metaprogramming. What I consider to be metaprogramming comes mostly from [Metaprogramming Ruby](http://pragprog.com/book/ppmetr/metaprogramming-ruby) which happens to be [on sale](http://pragprog.com/news/black-friday-cyber-monday-40-off-sale) through Monday.

Comment: @joofsh If I did that, would I be able to access `good_attrs` in my `Model`? That's where I am doing this, not in my view.

Comment: Actually...the more I think about it, perhaps just whitelisting all the attributes first would be easiest. So I am going to accept @Beerlington's answer instead. Thanks for your feedback though.

Comment: Creating a good_attrs method in the Model would be accessible yes. I'm saying do what Beerlington said, but better to pull it out into its own `good_attrs` method first (cleaner code). That way you know exactly where all the whitelisted attributes are defined, and its more reusable elsewhere in your code beyond just this one loop.